# How to add columns to the list control in windows phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, list, windows-phone-7

I want to add columns to the list control. I want to create them on run time because the column no may vary during execution. So how can i do it?

Comment: Are you looking to add columns to the list as a whole or individual ListItems? What have you tried?

Comment: i want to add items in the list but they should be shown like I1 I2 I3 I4 not it separate rows. I tried to do it with grid but i m stuck with make them scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, having a truly variable number of colums is a bad idea as you can't control what the app will look like and you coudl easily end up with something that looks very bad, is difficult to read, or both.

If you're looking to add multiple columns for each row in a list (I've done similar to display sports league tables) then add a grid to the ListItemTemplate, being sure to set a fixed width of each cell.

If you just want to make a list that scrolls horizontally instead of vertically you can do that with the following:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" 
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <!-- Could be a VirtualizingStackPanel if you wish -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Style set to enhance need for scrolling -->
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
                           Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

*Note that scrollbar visibility also controls whether it is possible to scroll.*

Comment: It worked fine thanks for that. But there is problem with it. Suppose i scrolled the list to 10 items then i selected an item from the list. Now when i refill the list with new items then after loading, the display shows the items from the last scrolled position. I want to reset the scrolling to first item. i tried listbox scrollintoview(object) by passing the first item of the listbox but it doesn't worked. i there a way to do so.

Comment: @rubyraj if you want to reset the position just call `ScrollToVerticalOffset(0)` on the internal scrollviewer.